# Adding more then just the Action and Object text to ticker, need to add a note

Tags: facebook-opengraph, ticker

I am building timeline posting for a fantasy trading company.

Currently the ticker displays as:
Joe Shmoe just [Bought|Sold] [{stock_name}] on {Site_Name}

I need it to say:
Joe Shmoe just [Bought|Sold] [{stock_name}] **in fantasy trading** on {Site_Name}

How would I add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible.

OG story title is formed of "{user} {action} {object} on {app name}"

Comment: we really need that line for legal reasons.. is there anything we can do to get something similar on the ticker?

Comment: I presume if this is important for legal reason your company wouldn't mind spending the time, effort and $$$ to become a Facebook partner and have Facebook put an exception into their code for you app.